# How might I execute this nested for loop in parallel?

Tags: bash, for, parallelism, gnu-parallel, concurrency

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

TARGETS=(
"81.176.235.2"
"81.176.70.2" 
"78.41.109.7" 
)

myIPs=(
"185.164.100.1"
"185.164.100.2"
"185.164.100.3"
"185.164.100.4"
"185.164.100.5"
)

for t in "${TARGETS[@]}"
  do 
    for a in "${myIPs[@]}"
    do 
      echo "${a} ${t} -p 80" >>log 2>&1 &
      echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" >>log 2>&1 &
      wait
    done 
    
done
```

I want this code to start with echo commands for each IP in `TARGETS` executing them in parallel. At the same time the script is not meant to proceed with echo commands for more than one address in `myIPs` simulteously, hence I introduced `wait` in the internal loop.
I want to have pairs of `echo` (each for the port `80` and `443`) executed in parallel for each target in `TARGETS`. In other words I want to accomplish this (but sadly it does not work):

```
for t in "${TARGETS[@]}"
do &
  for a in "${myIPs[@]}"
  do 
    echo "${a} ${t} -p 80" >>log 2>&1 &
    echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" >>log 2>&1 &
    wait
  done 

done
wait
```

Yet, because it would increase my load averages too much, I do not want this: :

```
for t in "${TARGETS[@]}"
do
  for a in "${myIPs[@]}"
  do 
    echo "${a} ${t} -p 80" >>log 2>&1 &
    echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" >>log 2>&1 &
  done 
done
wait
```

How might I accomplish my objective?

P.S. This is just a snippet of a more complex script. I wanted isolate the relevant issue, hence the use of `echo` instead of one of the networking commands.

Comment: I was going to comment by suggesting GNU Parallel, but you seem to have already tagged that. Did you try to do it with Parallel, or look at the other Q&A's there about it? (I didn't look the concrete issue too closely, just thought about the choice of tool.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, I did try it: `parallel -j0 'for a in "${myIPs[@]}"; do echo "${a} ${t} -p 80" >>log 2>&1; echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" >>log 2>&1;done' ::: "for t in ${TARGETS[@]}"` but it does not work. I don't understand `parallel` very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your question hard to understand: you seem to want both parallel and sequential execution.

Do you want this?

```bash
for t in "${TARGETS[@]}"; do 
  (
    for a in "${myIPs[@]}"; do 
      echo "${a} ${t} -p 80" >>log 2>&1 &
      echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" >>log 2>&1 &
      wait
    done 
  ) & 
done
```

each target's for loop is run in a subshell in the background.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. The trick with parentheses - that' exactly what I was looking for, I guess you call it [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should reverse the two loops, and put the wait between the `done`s. Like

```
for a in "${myIPs[@]}"
  do    for t in "${TARGETS[@]}"
          do    echo "${a} ${t} -p 80"  2>&1 &
                echo "${a} ${t} -p 443" 2>&1 &
          done 
        wait
  done
```

For each IP in `myIPs`, it would send a packet of two ports to each of the three `TARGETS`, and then wait for those six to finish.